# Show Hide With Jquery Want to add a Minus Sign when it is showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hide, show

I am using the following code, which is working great but I would like to switch out the `<div id"Show">` with the `<div id"hide">` when the Show is active. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
    <!--Script for Show Hide-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("#aboutcontent").hide();
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("#aboutcontent").show();
  });
});
</script>
<!--/script for show hide-->
```

HTML:

```
<div class="homepage-acecontent">
<div id="show"><img align="left"  style="margin-right:5px;" src="/template/images/btn-expand.png" border="0" alt="" /> ABOUT GENUINE H-D<sup>&reg;</sup> WORK WEAR</div>
<div id="hide"><img align="left"  style="margin-right:5px;" src="/template/images/btn-close.png" border="0" alt="" /></div>
<div id="aboutcontent">Content to show and hide goes here<!--/aboutcontent--></div>
<!--/homepage-acecontent--></div>
```

CSS:

```
 .homepage-acecontent{float:left; width: 1148px; color:#ff6418; font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; margin-left:40px;}
#aboutcontent{float:left; width: 1148px; color:#fff; font-size:14px; font-weight:normal; **display:none;**}
#aboutcontent a:link, #aboutcontent a:visited{color:#ff6418; text-decoration:none;}
#aboutcontent a:hover{color:#f68428;}
#show{cursor:pointer;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
    $("#aboutcontent").hide();
    $("#show").show();
    $(this).hide();
}).hide();
$("#show").click(function(){
    $("#aboutcontent").show();
    $("#hide").show();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Which will hide the div you press on and show the other one.It will also default the hide div to hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Don't switch the ids, switch the class.

You could do this instead:

```
<div id="button_1" class="show"></div>
<div id="button_2" class="hide"></div>
```

Then use `.addClass` and `.removeClass` to swap the classes.

Typically you want to avoid doing any kind of style manipulation. Switching classes is the preferred way to go because all your states are pre-defined and explicit; you can make a static HTML page that shows you all states. Even using `.show()` or `.hide()` violates this principle.

Answer (score 1):

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#control").click(function(){
    this.classToggle("hide");
    $("#aboutcontent").toggle();
  });
});
```

html:

```
<div id="control"> ABOUT GENUINE H-D<sup>&reg;</sup> WORK WEAR</div>
<div id="aboutcontent">Content to show and hide goes here<!--/aboutcontent--></div>
<!--/homepage-acecontent--></div>
```

css:

```
#control {
   cursor:pointer;
   background-image:url("/template/images/btn-expand.png");
   padding-left:50px; /* your image width */
   margin-right:5px;
   text-align:right;
}
#control .hide{
   background-image:url("/template/images/btn-close.png");
}
```

ref:

- http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/
- http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery to change the ID ussing the attr method

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("#aboutcontent").hide();
    $(this).attr("id","Show");
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("#aboutcontent").show();
    $(this).attr("id","Hide");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but I think you're asking how to show the hide button when the show button is clicked and vice versa? If so...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#hide").click(function(){
          $("#aboutcontent,#hide").hide();
          $("#show").show();
      });
      $("#show").click(function(){
          $("#aboutcontent,#hide").show();
          $("#show").hide();
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your current code, the easiest thing to do is update your JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("#aboutcontent").hide();

    //Toggle show/hide
    $(this).hide();
    $("#show").show();
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("#aboutcontent").show();

    //Toggle show/hide
    $(this).hide();
    $("#hide").show();
  });
});
</script>
```

There are some other optimizations you could make to the html/JS to make this more efficient, but this will get you started and solve your issue.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. I have tried it and it does exactly what I was asking for.